# Is there a way to add the mouse event to an Action in Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, xcode, xamarin, interface-builder

Is there a way to add the mouse event to an Action in Interface Builder?

Currently in my ViewController.h I have this:

```
- (IBAction)myStepperAction:(id)sender;
```

In my ViewController.m I have this:

```
- (IBAction)myStepperAction:(id)sender { }
```

In my event handler I have the following:
(I'm using C# but I can read some Swift)

```
    partial void myStepperAction(Foundation.NSObject sender) {
        var stepper = sender as NSStepper;
    }
```

If I add a second argument I get an error:

```
    partial void myStepperAction(Foundation.NSObject sender, Event event) {
        var stepper = sender as NSStepper;
        var value = event.CTRLKey==true ? stepper.DoubleValue + 10 : stepper.DoubleValue;
    }
```

> CS0759: No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of
> partial method 'ViewController.myStepperAction(NSObject, EventArgs)'

Is there a way to pass the event to a partial method? Or is there a way to get an application mouse event?

What I want to do is when the stepper is clicked, check if the CTRL or SHIFT key is also pressed to make it increment by 10 instead of 1.

Comment: If I understand correctly do you want to increase the value by 1 when directly  click on the stepper, and increase the value by 10 when click on the stepper with press CTRL or SHIFT key ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CGEventSourceKeyState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408768-cgeventsourcekeystate) to detect whether the specific key is pressed currently or not .

And you can find the exact number for `control` in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125341/8187800) .

It should be `0x3B` .

Check the code used in Xamarin below

```
partial void myStepperAction(Foundation.NSObject sender) {
    var stepper = sender as NSStepper;

    bool isCtrlPressed = CGEventSource.GetKeyState(0,0x3b);
    var value = isCtrlPressed ? stepper.DoubleValue + 10 : stepper.DoubleValue;
       
}
```

Comment: This works great. Would you happen to know if the user presses the up or down button?

Comment: Just find the code in the link i provided , the code for up and down button is `0x7E` and `0x7D` .

Comment: I didn't word that fully. I meant the buttons on the stepper. I've created a separate question for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713746/way-to-check-if-up-or-down-button-is-pressed-with-nsstepper